# Azure App Service getting "503 Service Unavailable" after deploying through DevOps pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have asp.net core web app that has been running fine in an Azure app service for the past couple of years. I have regularly published new versions of the app using the "Publish" feature in Visual Studio 2019, and have never received the 503 error while the app service is running. I recently set up a multi-stage release pipeline for the app in Azure DevOps. The first stage of the pipeline deploys the build to an Azure app service that we use as a test environment. The second stage has an approval condition set up on it and after the approval is completed, it deploys the build to the app service in our production environment.

This is my first deployment using the pipeline. For the past couple weeks, I've deployed builds through the first stage of the pipeline and tested the app service with no problems. When we approved the build for Stage 2, the pipeline completed successfully (with no errors in the logs) and the build was deployed to our production environment. However, when I try to access the app service I receive a "503 Service Unavailable" error.

I have tried restarting the app service (several times), and compared the configurations between our test and production environments, but did not find any significant differences between the them. I compared the pipeline stages and the only difference I saw was the app services they deployed to.

Unable to resolve the issue, I ended up setting the "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" setting to "0" and published the app from Visual Studio, instead of using the pipeline. This was done only as a temporary work-around, so our users would not experience an extended outage while I work to resolve the pipeline issue.

So, now I need to figure out what is causing the 503 error when I deploy through the pipeline. If anyone has some suggestions on how I can fix the issue, or point me in the direction of what to look for, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: which SKU is your app service plan?

Comment: I've gotten 503's when the app fails to start. My problems usually were failures in variable replacements in the appsettings.json file. You can use the App Service Editor (preview) in the azure portal to check what was released if you're using release variables.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SKU. Is that the app service plan pricing tier? If so, it is an S3 tier app service plan.

Comment: I'm not using any variable replacements in the pipeline. I have separate appsettings.json files set up for each environment, which is determined by the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" variable that is set in the app settings within the configuration of the Azure App Service itself.

Comment: You could deploy your code to a [deployment slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) from your Azure Pipeline to avoid causing any downtime to your actual application.

Comment: Also, 502s can be caused due to many reasons. Please run through your setup through this [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503) to narrow down the issue and post your findings here so we can take another look.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. I tried deploying a new version of the app through the pipeline earlier this week and had the same issue. Restarting the app service resolves the issue for a few minutes, but before I can even warm-up all the routes I start getting the 503 error again. I ended up publishing from Visual Studio to resolve the issue. Microsoft's troubleshooting guide was of little help.

Comment: @blue_thunder, has anything changed for you on this front?  We are experiencing the same issue now with our App Service.  We are using one of the slots for our development environment, and seemingly randomly, the app goes down, azure portal claims the site is unhealthy, and we continuously get 503 errors.  After a restart, if I wait like 10 minutes, it seems to come back online for a while.  But there doesn't seem to be a pattern to which is starts failing again.  Just wondering if you found a resolution.

Comment: I just found out what is causing it for us.  We use Azure DevOps for building and release pipelines.  Starting this week, if a build pipeline finishes successfully, we have our release pipeline triggered to deploy the artifact.  If we deploy through this trigger (completing a PR, for example), the site goes down and send 503.  But if we use Azure DevOps to create another release, using the same artifact and release pipeline, the site comes back up just fine.  It is the triggered deployments that cause the issue for us.